# Phone App + Online Database?

Tags: iphone, database, authentication

Idea: Create an database that I can integrate with an iPhone app.

As I have never worked very in-depth with online databases, I need advice on what methods are best for creating a database. The database would need to contain a list of usernames and passwords to login.

P.S. - I have my own website server.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing would be to just use MySQL probably. Then you would define web services that expose basic access to the entities in the database. Best to do those with REST. That might be more than you are up for.

The problem with lesser solutions is that you can't have users just connecting directly to a db from the mobile app. So you have to have something talking to the db.

The other option would be to try to implement the whole thing using Game Center, since that has support for players and scores, etc. Not sure if that would be sufficient. I have looked at it but not in a lot of depth and there are changes coming in iOS 5.

Comment: Stick with the app idea. I could give you some more detailed ideas of how to setup your database. It's going to be a very simple schema and exposing it through web services could be very simple. Have you ever written any Java? With Java EE 6 you can make a project, put in a few entities, and then even expose the web services without writing much of any code. What you are describing here would be accomplishable in a few days.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion there is no need to bother with the iPhone app, just make a mobile version of the website. At the end of the day, you'll have to write the website infrastructure anyway, and with a website there is no need to worry about distribution. You'll even be able to support those using other devices.

Comment: Excellent point.  There's a book out there, [Building iPhone Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596805784/) , on how to "skin" a web app to look like an iPhone app when viewed on an iPhone.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! For my website, I have created a mobile version [http://m.iminichrispy.com](http://m.iminichrispy.com), but I still have no idea how I would go about creating a database. Do you know any good online tutorials out there for this? I see the advantages to a web app, but I've never really done much html or java, and especially nothing with website databases.

Comment: There are a ton of tutorials out there, but before you dive into that you'll have to decide what language you will be using on the server side. PHP? Ruby? Perl? Python? Pick a language, maybe a framework (Rails for ruby, Cake for PHP, etc), and then get started. Remember, you would have to this anyway if you were doing the iPhone app.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for ideas, I learned a lot of what I know of web-based databases from a book called *Head First PHP & MySQL*  (ISBN 978-0-596-00630-3).  I already knew SQL and C++ (C++ is similar in many ways to PHP), but you really don't need it with book.  It will teach you the very basics of both languages and how to tie them together.  It will also give you a good frame of reference to Google solutions or ask informed questions.